# Не могу подключить PostgreSQL к Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Настройки Django:

```
DATABASES = {
       'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'links_db',
        'USER': 'djuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'duser1',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Вот как я создавал БД:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE links_db;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# CREATE USER djuser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'duser1';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=#  ALTER ROLE djuser SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
ALTER ROLE djuser SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
ALTER ROLE djuser SET timezone TO 'UTC';
ALTER ROLE
ALTER ROLE
ALTER ROLE
postgres=#  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE links_db TO djuser;
GRANT
```

Вот что получилось:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "djuser"
```

Answer (score 0):

Определения того, каким пользователям с каких машин и каким образом разрешено авторизовываться для доступа к базам, указаны в файле конфигурации Postgres pg_hba.conf.
С документацией можно ознакомится, например, тут:
https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/auth-pg-hba-conf

В вашем случае вам нужно добавить в файл конфигурации строку, которая разрешит авторизовываться по хешу пароля (md5) как минимум пользователю djuser по паролю при доступе к машина с IP-адресом 127.0.0.1 к базе links_db.

Answer (score 0):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'links_db',
        'USER': 'djuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'duser1',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

ну и установите сам psycopg2

```
# pip3 install psycopg2
```